# PIC 16F648A memory getting corrupted some time after programming

Tags: pic

While learning PIC programming I suddenly encounter the problem that the programmed information from the .hex files gets corrupted after a while. After reprogramming everything works fine but after a while it looks as if the EEPROM of the PIC gets corrupted. What could be the cause. I have no clue where to look.

The power supply of the PIC is a lab supply at 5V DC. The power lines on the experimental print have 2 capacitors. 1 220uF over the power and one capacitor of 0.1 uF directly over the supply terminals of the PIC.

I am working on a four digit timer. the timer pics up the required preset information from the EEPROM before the counting starts and puts the information in 4 display registers. These registers are scanned by the interupt routine. The counting cycle works fine. But when I want to select a new preset value. The EEPROM returns a non existing value. Verification of the PIC in the programmer indicates that that the the programming is no longer identical to the information in the hex.

The error must be in writing to the EEPROM. Since the overwritten positions in the EEPROM are not always the same I suspect that I have to look for an error just prior to the actual writing cycle.  So back to the debugging.

Comment: Is the read-back voltage exactly the same as the programming rail voltage during writes? (I'm not sure if there is an internal voltage converter used inside your PIC for programming -- do you know, if so?) Also, I now remember having some trouble programming EEPROM on PIC controllers. But the reason, my vague memory barely recalls, had something to do with not carefully reading all the docs including the errata. Once I'd done that, I remember inserting a single NOP to add an additional cycle of delay and that everything worked perfectly after that. I suspect this may be the issue here.

Comment: I can't find a datasheet for the PIC16F634A. You have a link at Microchip for that?

Comment: I am using the PIC 16F648A. Have also added some more info in the question. I dont mind to start reading again and will do so. But maybe someone has an idea

Comment: I still can't find the datasheet, though. Perhaps I'm just clueless. Can you provide a link?

Comment: Excusses. I made a mistake with the PIC number

Comment: Oh! So look at the title, now! Got it.

Comment: Are you following the EXAMPLE 13-2, precisely? Or not doing any writes at all, programmatically? Also check EXAMPLE 13-1 for reading. Are you doing that?

Comment: At this moment I already know from the example number that you are referring to the required writing cycle. That cycle is followed. See more info in the edited question

Comment: It's coming back to me! It was during the READ that I found one problem I had. In fact, I had to prove this case to Microchip decades ago on their PIC16F family using the ICE 2000 system I had, so that I could actually TRACE the behavior and provide a complete log of events. A part of the solution was to _IGNORE_ the PIC documentation which stated "The data is available, in the very next cycle, in the EEDATA register; therefore it can be read in the next instruction." This wasn't true. Also, if an interrupt occurred just right, things entirely screwed up too. I'll answer with some thoughts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50795/discussion-between-decapod-and-jonk).